# How can I find the index in react js and change dropdown value as per previous dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `multiple dropdowns` in react js & each row have two dropdowns like `first for Gender & second for Names`

The list is displaying properly but I want to when user will select first dropdown then second dropdown should be open as per previous dropdown value.

Like if user select Gender Male in first dropdown then in second dropdown only male names should be display if user select Gender Female in first dropdown then in second dropdown only female names should be display.

My Code:-

```js
const body = [
        {
            "Field_ID": 1,
            "FieldName_CR": "Sohan",
            "gender_ID": 1,
            "male": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 2,
            "FieldName_CR": "Mohan",
            "gender_ID": 1,
            "male": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 3,
            "FieldName_CR": "Gaurav",
            "gender_ID": 1,
            "male": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 4,
            "FieldName_CR": "Hakim",
            "gender_ID": 1,
            "male": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 5,
            "FieldName_CR": "Sumit",
            "gender_ID": 1,
            "male": "Male"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 9,
            "FieldName_CR": "Neha",
            "gender_ID": 2,
            "female": "Female"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 10,
            "FieldName_CR": "Seema",
            "gender_ID": 2,
            "female": "Female"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 11,
            "FieldName_CR": "Anuradha",
            "gender_ID": 2,
            "female": "Female"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 12,
            "FieldName_CR": "Meenu",
            "gender_ID": 2,
            "female": "Female"
        },
        {
            "Field_ID": 13,
            "FieldName_CR": "Harsha",
            "gender_ID": 2,
            "female": "Female"
        }
    ]
    
    
const[body, setBody] = useState([]);
const[name, setName] = useState([]);

setBody(body);
setName([...new Set(body.map(item => item.gender_ID))]);
      console.log(body);
    
    
     return (
    <>
    <Box>
      <TextField
                      className="ruleContainer"
                      select
                      name="gender"
                      label="Gender"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                      value={inputField.gender}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)
                      }
                    >
                      {name ? name.map((opt) => (
                        <MenuItem key={opt} value={opt}>
                          {opt}
                        </MenuItem>
                      )) : ''}
                    </TextField>
                    
                      <TextField
                      className="ruleContainer"
                      select
                      name="name"
                      label="Name"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                      value={inputField.name}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)
                      }
                    >
                       {body ? body.map((opt) => (
                        <MenuItem key={opt} value={opt}>
                          {opt.FieldName_CR}
                        </MenuItem>
                      )) : ''}
                    </TextField>
    </Box>
    
    
     <Box>
      <TextField
                      className="ruleContainer"
                      select
                      name="gender"
                      label="Gender"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                      value={inputField.gender}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)
                      }
                    >
                      {name ? name.map((opt) => (
                        <MenuItem key={opt} value={opt}>
                          {opt}
                        </MenuItem>
                      )) : ''}
                    </TextField>
                    
                      <TextField
                      className="ruleContainer"
                      select
                      name="name"
                      label="Name"
                      variant="outlined"
                      size="small"
                      value={inputField.name}
                      onChange={(event) =>
                        handleChangeInput(inputField.id, event)
                      }
                    >
                       {body ? body.map((opt) => (
                        <MenuItem key={opt} value={opt}>
                          {opt.FieldName_CR}
                        </MenuItem>
                      )) : ''}
                    </TextField>
    </Box>
      </>
      )
```

Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

For getting the index, The map function can also return the index and each item in the array. For example:

```
array.map((item, index) => {};
```

item will be the object in your array. and index will be the index.

As for your other question you didn't like your handleChangeInput() function for the body. you can add to that function when it selects the body it sets the names to a filtered list of the names.

Comment: I'm not talking about map index actually I have multiple rows & each rows have two dropdown & when I change anything in first dropdown then I want to change data in second dropdown so how can i find second dropdown ? and change the values?